# Error using movie command in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I generated multiple images which I converted into frames with im2frame in order to create a movie. I used this code:

```
for i = 10:20
    images = sprintf('img%d.jpg',i); 
    ImageData = imread(images); 
    M(i) = im2frame(ImageData); 
end 
movie(M)
movie2avi(M,'sonar.avi','compression','None','fps',5,'quality',100)
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Error using hgMovie
Movie contains uninitialized frames

Error in movie (line 41)
        builtin('hgMovie',varargin{:});

Error in open83B_edited_2 (line 324)
movie(M)
```

Does anyone have a clue what might be wrong with my code? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're getting that error is because there are some frames in your movie that are uninitialized - meaning there is no data.  This makes sense because in your loop, you are starting to write into the `M` array at index 10 when you should be starting it at 1.  As such, the first 9 frames in your video are empty and MATLAB doesn't like that :).

With that, I suspect it has to do with your loop index.  Consider changing the `M(i)` statement to this:

```
M(i-9) = im2frame(ImageData);
```

This way you can preserve your image filename format, while properly writing into the array starting at index 1.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I noticed that I can also just remove the index, and just add: M = im2frame(ImageData). But now I got a further error in movie2avi, namely: "Error using movie2avi (line 57)
Inputs must be a MATLAB movie, a filename, and param/value pairs.
"

Comment: You need the index there or else you will **only** store the most recent read-in frame in `M`. Also, I'm not sure why you're getting that error if you are properly converting each image into a movie frame structure. Maybe try initializing your `M` array first so that it belongs to a proper MATLAB movie structure. Try using this statement before your loop: `M(1:11) = struct('cdata', [] 'colormap', []);`